# Grouping overlapping time intervals in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

There is a dataset with columns `date_from` and `date_to` in Oracle 10g (or rather just `date_from`, because the length is constant).

I need to collapse overlapping intervals, e.g. these rows:

```
date_from  date_to
2015-01-01 2015-01-10
2015-01-03 2015-01-11
```

need to become:

```
2015-01-01 2015-01-11
```

I wonder if there is a way to query this neatly in one go without using cursors... my query is huge and still doesn't collapse everything in edge cases. Maybe there is some SQL extension in Oracle 10g for problems like this that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH data (date_from, date_to) AS (
    SELECT DATE'2015-01-01', DATE'2015-01-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE'2015-01-03', DATE'2015-01-11' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    min(date_from) date_from, max(date_to) date_to 
FROM (
    SELECT
        date_from, date_to,
        sum(merge) OVER (ORDER BY date_from) group_id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            date_from, date_to,
            case when date_from <= lag(date_to) OVER (ORDER BY date_from)
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE 1
            end as merge
        FROM data)
    ) intervals
GROUP BY group_id
ORDER BY min(intervals.date_from);
```

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this?! Many thanks, `LAG() OVER()` is what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

My data also contains smaller non-overlapping date ranges, engulfed with one large date range. This solution does not cover that scenario.
E.g.

```
WITH
  DATA (DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) AS
    (SELECT DATE '2015-01-01', DATE '2015-01-20' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATE '2015-01-02', DATE '2015-01-04' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATE '2015-01-05', DATE '2015-01-07' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATE '2015-01-08', DATE '2015-01-10' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATE '2015-01-11', DATE '2015-01-13' FROM DUAL)
  --=======================================================================
  SELECT MIN(DATE_FROM) DATE_FROM, MAX(DATE_TO) DATE_TO
    FROM (
           SELECT DATE_FROM, DATE_TO, SUM(MERGE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_FROM) GROUP_ID
             FROM (SELECT DATE_FROM, DATE_TO, CASE WHEN DATE_FROM <= LAG(DATE_TO) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_FROM) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS MERGE FROM DATA)
         ) INTERVALS
GROUP BY GROUP_ID
ORDER BY MIN(INTERVALS.DATE_FROM)
```

Output produces 4 rows, iso just one:

```
DATE_FROM   DATE_TO
2015/01/01  2015/01/20
2015/01/05  2015/01/07
2015/01/08  2015/01/10
2015/01/11  2015/01/13
```